# SAS Loop - Array

Tags: arrays, sas

I have the following data set:

```
data abc;
infile xyz;
input test $9;
      q1 $3
      q2 $3
      .
      qn $3;
```

I wanna create a loop that allows to check for a specific condition (if the first 2 characters are not 07 then do) on all those 'q' variables and then get all the 'test' variables that meet that condition.

I've been trying this

```
data loop;
set abc;`
array q{15};`
if substri(q{15},1,2) = "07" then do;`
run;
```

The input looks like this

```
test     q1     q2    q3........qn
cust1   0000   0700  0800     0700
cust2   0000   0700  0800     0900
cust3   0000   0000  0800     0900
cust 4  0700   0000  0800     0900
```

Based on the condition that i wanna set the test column only for those cases where the first 2 characters is 07. The result should be

```
test     q1     q2    q3........qn
cust1   ----   0700  ----     0700
cust2   ----   0700  ----    ----
cust 4  0700   ----  ----     ----
```

Comment: Please could you post an example of the output you're trying to produce and the input used to generate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want missing values in `q1-qn` when the first two characters are 07 in the input dataset, you could do something like this:

```
data want;
    set have;
    array q{15} $;
    output_flag = 0;
    do i = 1 to 15;
        if q[i] eq: '07' then output_flag + 1;
        else call missing(q[i]);
    end;
    drop i;
    if output_flag then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost have your answer - just follow through on your if statement:

```
data loop;
set abc;
array q{15} $;
do i = 1 to 15;
    if substri(q{i},1,2) = "07" then do;
       q{i} = q{i};
    else
       q{i} = "";
    end;
end;
run;
```

Comment: This wouldn't eliminate rows where none of the `q[i] ` begin with 07, which seems to be a requirement here.

Comment: You're right! and your solution is very nice.  Still, a simple thing to fix with another if clause but not as elegant as your solution